# How to auto run moonlight-qt in console after auto login?

Tags: raspbian, systemd-startup

`moonlight-qt` runs in the terminal without desktop environment fine but I would like it to auto launch after auto login. I tried creating systemd service to do this but nothing happened.

[Edit] This is the service file I created which works. (can't add answer because I am new)

```
[Unit]
Description=moonlight gamestream client

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/moonlight-qt

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Service file path: `/lib/systemd/system/moonlight.service`

Enable service: `sudo systemctl enable moonlight.service`

Comment: Without addressing your specific question (which is unclear without code) like the thousands of similar questions ANY attempt to start any code which performs I/O is futile at boot on any OS.